# I can't type a javascript expression with Circumflex in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code

When i want to write:

```
const my expr = /^(begins_with_Circumflex)/i
```

Than Visual Studio Code makes this:

```
const expr = /⁽begins_with_Circumflex)/i
```

How can I prevent this from happening,any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found error in settings,now everything works fine.